# Upgrading WebApi OData v3 project to OData v4

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I am in the middle of development project based on EntityFramework, WebApi and Odata.

I started this project when OData v3 was current and created a number of controllers derived from **EntitySetController**.

I have attempted to upgrade my project to support oData v4 using the latest release from the OData team.

There are a number of namespace and other changes in the v4 Nuget packages.http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx

I think that I have worked past these problems, however it appears that **EntitySetController** has been removed from the code base in v4. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1715

What is the best approach to upgrading my code?

Is the code for the deprecated EntitySetController class available so that I can bring it into my project?

Answer (score 0):

For update EntitySetController class, here is the suggestion:

a. Inherit from ODataController instead of EntitySetController

b. Instead of void, user types, HttpResponseMessage, and CLR types, return IQueryable, SingleResult, IHttpActionResult from your actions

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for you response.  I decided to create a new WebApi project and rebuild all my existing controllers using your suggestions.
Unfortunately I was unable to ascertain the correct set of Nuget packages to install to support OData V4.
Does OData V4 still require the pre-release version of Web API 2.2 on WebstackNightly?
Is there a list of the names and sources of the Nuget packages required for OData V4 anywhere?

Comment: Just in the middle of an implementation of OData V4 on top of WebAPI 2.2 (using RTM versions of packages). Be aware: OData V4 has some strange behaviors atm. Like, $metadata is only available in XML format, query results (with $select/$expand) are only available in JSON format. Current versions of DataJS/BreezeJS are NOT V4 compliant (yet) and will not work together. (Differences in expected  HTTP headers, differences in WebAPI Controller/Formatters usage).